# Click a Button with data-toggle and data-target using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape with the following HTML by clicking on a button:

I have tried appIE.document.getElementById("btnAddFruit").click

```
<button type="button"

data-toggle="modal" data-target="#secondary-dialog" 
id="btnAddFruit" 
class="edt  btn btn-red pull-right margin-left-10">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">

</span> Fruits</button>
```

The IE also does not show the pop up window.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I made a typo on the ID and have corrected it

Comment: if url can be added please do so

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't provide the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused as the id shown is `btnAddFruit`

```
ie.document.querySelector("#btnAddFruit").click
```

Which is equivalent to

```
ie.document.getElementById("btnAddFruit").click
```

Otherwise, please detail what the error message is and on which line (show more of your code as well would help)

Comment: The error msg for your code gives:
Run-time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property or method



,if i do,
Set obj = appie.document.getelementbyid("btnAddFruit")
my obj will be created of type "Variant/Object/HTMLButtonElement"

Comment: Fine. I guess you are using an older IE version or your emulation is set to older version. I have updated answer to show both syntax versions.

Comment: I'm using IE 11 (Specifically 11.437.17763.0). Which software emulation?

Comment: if you look in the emulation tab via dev tools F12  - what is the document mode?

Comment: Document mode: 11 (Default)

Comment: Sorry, I did it again on the url, it's 7 (default).

Comment: Change it to edge

Comment: Or 11 if edge not listed

Comment: How do I change it to 11 using a line in vba? 
the code works once i've changed the IE version on IE. thanks for your help

Comment: Use the dropdown in dev tools

Comment: @SIM Aghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.... editing on tiny screen mobile..... now fixed on laptop. Thank you for checking - much appreciated.